# Visualization: Oscillations of Spring- FLASH

Tags: apache-flex, visualization

I want to visualize spring oscillations and hence need to create a visual of a spring- stretching and vibrations. I am working in Flash with need to demo oscilations based on user input. Typically, the springs are represented as a pencil sketch like below, and wanted to check if something more 3D and natural that can be built without much complexity(e.g would like stretch/ compression shows up on color of the spring body etc). Thanks again for and guidance/ pointers.

http://www.flashkit.com/movies/Scripting/Physics/Damped_o-Achyut_V-877 0/index.php

Comment: working link: http://www.flashkit.com/movies/Scripting/Physics/Damped_o-Achyut_V-8770/index.php

Comment: What type of 3D are you interested in pseudo 3D using 2D drawing APIs or "real 3d" (still pseudo but think you know what I mean, triangle based rather than just line drawing) this can be done pretty easily good info here http://www.engineersedge.com/spring_tension_calc_k.htm and here http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flash/molehill/ please elaborate a bit, what are the extent of the characteristics/physics you expect it to account for, obviously not going quantum mechanics and up :), also how 3d does it need to be? set perspective or moving camera, desired detail etc.

Comment: sorry- Shaunhusain; missed this till now. I am looking at the pseudo3D... want to be able to show the depth/ spring coil without hurting myself too much with complex rendering. Set perspective is good enough. I checked the away3D functionality for representing block on inclined plane- and if I have something quick that I can build off that would be ideal...